# Can jquery return height of an element as a percentage?

Tags: jquery

`$('#my_div').height('50%')` will set the height but how can you retrieve the div's current height as a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert get height in px and convert them to percenatge

```
1em = 12pt = 16px = 100%
```

Comment: Ok, I was thinking something like this would be the only way. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/), which returns just the number (i.e, without the unit symbol). Perfect for percentage, which of course needs no units. From the docs:

> The `.height()` method
>   is recommended when an element's
>   height needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation.

So you can try something like this:

```
var height_pct = Math.round( 
    $('#my_div').height() / 
    $('#my_div').parent().height() * 100
    );
```

Comment: maybe jquery changed this, but the ".height()" of my 70% div is 564.

Comment: That sounds right. `height()` returns the number of "pixels" comprising the height of the element being measured, with no units (so no "px"). I have "pixels" in quotes because with high-resolution screens, they may not literally be pixels these days.

Answer (score 0):

So Simple
$("#eleid")[0].style.width

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the element you'll get it's percentage value.

```
<div id="a" style ="height: 300px; background: green; display: none;">
    a
    <div id="b" style ="height: 10%; background: blueviolet;">
        b
    </div>
    <div id="c" style ="height: 20%; background: cornflowerblue;">                        
        c
    </div>        
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // height outside of event     
    $("#a").append($("#a").height());
    $("#b").append($("#b").height());
    $("#c").append($("#c").height());

    // height inside of event               
    $("*").click(function(){                
        $("#a").css("display", "block");
        $("#a").append($("#a").height());
        $("#b").append($("#b").height());
        $("#c").append($("#c").height());
    })
}) 
</script>
```

Notice that the value is different inside an event function.

**Addition Notes:**

> The value reported by .height() is not guaranteed to be accurate when
> the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure
> the element is visible before using .height(). jQuery will attempt to
> temporarily show and then re-hide an element in order to measure its
> dimensions, but this is unreliable and (even when accurate) can
> significantly impact page performance. This show-and-rehide
> measurement feature may be removed in a future version of jQuery.

**Source:** [jQuery height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3482260/4695159), for a fixed div like a panel, that is what worked for me:

```
    var h = Math.round(
        $('#my_div').height() /
        $(window).height() * 100
    );
```