# jQuery css('left') reports 'px' instead of '%'

Tags: jquery, css

Just stumbled across a problem which I am sure must have a simple explanation that just eludes me today for some reason.

If I want to determine the CSS setting for an element absolutely positioned with a precentage value, jQuery only returns the pixel value (
http://jsfiddle.net/xTUR3/2/):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrp">test</div>
<div id="out">$('wrp').css('left') = <span></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrp {
   position: absolute;
   left: -150%;
   width: 200%;
   background-color: green;
   height: 50%;    
}

#out {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;    
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrp = $('#wrp');
    $('#out span').html(wrp.css('left'));
});
```

EDIT: Anyone got an idea whether there's a way retrieve the precentage value without writing a dedicated px-to-%-conversion function?

Comment: A little search... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482177/can-jquery-return-height-of-an-element-as-a-percentage

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xTUR3/3/ is displaying -150% for me...

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar Interesting... Webkit browsers spit out the % value...

Comment: Try in Firefox and you get `-1299px`. Seems like a cross-browser issue.

Comment: @elclanrs ...which would be indicative of a jQuery bug, I'd say.

Comment: I haven't looked but it's possible that it just uses a native javascript method which could be the root of the problem (difference).

Comment: Seems to have been introduced with version 1.4.4, see first comment on this page http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Make little sample for [you](http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/xTUR3/5/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lft = $('#wrp').css("left")+"";
    if (lft.match("px")) {
        lft = (lft.split("px").join("")*1/$('#wrp').parent().width())*100;
        if ($.browser == "msie")
            lft = lft>0 ? Math.ceil(lft) : Math.floor(lft);
        lft += "%";                     
    }
    $('#out span').html(lft);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I was wondering whether there's a native jQuery solution for this. I noticed that my original post wasn't clear enough so I have edited it.

Comment: On a side note `lft = parseInt(lft)/$('#wrp').parent().width()*100;` looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: i think it not jquery bug or problem, it problem of javascript engine in browser

Comment: Yeah, but isn't jQuery supposed to normalise javascript behaviour across different js engines?

Comment: It should also be noted that there is, and always will be, a margin of error with these conversions - http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/xTUR3/8/