# jquery if else not working in FF

Tags: jquery, firefox, if-statement

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     if($("#window").css('top') == '0%'){
       $("#window").stop().animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
     }
     else { 
        $("#window").stop().animate({top:'0%'},1000);
     }
 });
```

it works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox it works partially.

In FF it just works the `else` situation. identifies that the position isn't `top: '0%'` and change to `top: '0%'`, but doesn't change to `top: '-100%'` if is `top: '0%'`

Please suggest.

Comment: What's the value when you debug/log it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove percent symbol and use `top: 0;`

Comment: Firefox returns 'px' on 'top' and others 'position' functions, not percents, i wrote some function for akin post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320593/jquery-cssleft-reports-px-instead-of/9321104#9321104

Comment: dude, thank for your observation. but i need solve it with percentage, because the '#window' div is 'height: 100%', so to blind it is necessary use 'top: -100%'. you're totally correct, but i guess the problem is the '-100%', because  in all my attempts, the div moves to '0%' but never moves to '-100%'

Comment: but this occurs only using if and else situation. when i just use for an example, it works perfectly: $("#menuinformacoes").toggle(function(){
  $("#informacoes").animate({top:'0%'},1300);
  },function(){
     $("#informacoes").animate({top:'-100%'},1300);
     });

Comment: Firefox returns only "pixels" value