# auto resizing a div and all parent divs

Tags: html, css

A layout has the following arrangement: (using MVC3 - The whole html is in the `Layout.cshtml`)

- A Top header (containing a Banner and Menu bar)
- Contents (Divided in Left and Right panes).
- Footer

The contents of the Right pane contain tabs, and the height can vary depending on the opened tab.

I want to make the Contents div auto adjust to the height and not create a scrollbar (Not browser  scroll bar).

This is somewhat achieved but it breaks the rest of the `CSS`.

Here is the CSS :

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

body {
width: 100%;
/* height: 100%;    */
}

#Wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #6A89C1;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 750px;
    min-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

header {
    background-color: #abcdef;
    height: 19%;  /* did not keep it 20% due to some Background repeat issues.. */
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px outset #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;    
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#Banner {   
    height: 72%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#Menu {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;    
}

#Contents {
    height: auto; /*65%;*/
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;    
}

#Contents #LeftPane {
    background-color: #E9F1FF;
    border-right: 1px solid #B9D4FF;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 24.8%;  /* Should not be exactly 25% as it causes RightPane div to shift downwards  */    
}

#Contents #RightPane {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;    
    overflow: auto;
}

.Left {
    float: left;    
}

.Clear {
    clear: both;    
}

footer {
    background-color: #6A89C1;
    clear: both;
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#Wrapper, footer {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;    
}
```

[image: Layout screenshot]

The whole center part needs to grow automatically but the Layout (propotions) should be same

Attached also is the image after adjusting to the given `CSS`

[image: layout after adjustment]

**(notice the menu bar Bg and left pane & footer heights )**

Hope to have explained the question adequately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using heights all together, the browser will adjust element heights according to their contents.

Comment: a little similar to what was the applied solution . thats why marked as answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should get the opened tabs height with javascript (or jquery) and assign this height to the content container.

Comment: thank you for your response but the whole css is in % not px.. would it still work.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482177/can-jquery-return-height-of-an-element-as-a-percentage

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```
overflow: auto
```

causes scroll bar.

You are able to do this using javascript (when tab is changed then change height depending on height of tab). I'm not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: The old css did have a overflow:auto; for right pane and it showed the scrollbar. but the target is to grow the whole div and show only the main browser window scrollbar (not the scrollbar for a specific div). and taking the height from the jQuery may not work as the whole css is in percent not pixels..

Comment: but in jquery you can get height in px (even if it is set in % in css stylesheet). http://jsfiddle.net/CaAka/

Comment: if it will help, then please mark this as useful / as answer.

Comment: Tried your solution as well. And it did yield but promising results. Thanks to all again ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.. !

found a possible solution of not putting all the contents in the wrapper div rather independent of each other i.e.

```
 The Header div is separate div (parent is the body not the wrapper)

 same for Contents and footer div..
```

Kind regards and again thank you for all the suggestions,
A.Ali