# how do i make it so the 'mouseleave' function only executes if the divs height is 15%?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im relatively new to Jquery so pardon my incompetence but I have this function:

```
$('#contact').mouseleave(function () {

    $('#contact').animate({
        borderTopLeftRadius: "0%",
        borderTopRightRadius: "0%"
    }, 50);
    $('#contact').animate({
        height: "10%"
    }, 50);
    $('#home').animate({
        height: "80%"
    }, 50);
    $('#logo').animate({
        height: "45%"
    }, 50);
});
```

but I only want it to execute if the '#contact' height is 15%, i know the '.height()' only reads in pixels and since 15% could be any amount of pixels i need help writing an if statement

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height and https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var height = parseInt($("#contact").css("height"));
```

Than you can convert to percentage:

[Can jquery return height of an element as a percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3482177/7011883)

And then place the if statement before animations